# Choose class implementation at compile time

Tags: java

Suppose I have an `Animal` interface and particular classes implementing it `Cat` and `Dog`.  Right at the entry to the program, there's this:

```
if (choice == 0) {
    Animal A = new Cat();
}
else if (choice == 1) {
    Animal A = new Dog();
}
```

I'd like to have the `choice` parameter be populated  **at compile time** (e.g., during Maven build),   so that:

- if I compile with choice == 0, the Dog class doesn't get compiled
- if I compile with choice == 1, the Cat class doesn't get compiled

The reason for this is that 'Cat' and 'Dog' classes have separate/different dependencies.

Basically, the goal is to have one build for "A is a Cat" and another build for "A is a Dog". When I package the JAR, the use case for running the JAR
will be either for 'Cat' or for 'Dog' (depending on the environment), never both 'Cat' and 'Dog' - so, there is no need for all dependencies to be in the project.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the two implementations of `Animal` to two separate projects. Each project can have its own dependencies. Then you can package both projects independently of each other (including the respective dependencies) and only one implementation of `Animal` will be known at runtime.

You might end up with something like this:

```
base-animals
  ├ com.wang.animals.base.Animal
  └ com.wang.animals.base.AnimalFactory

dog-application
  ├ com.wang.animals.dogs.Dog
  └ application.properties // animalClass=com.wang.animals.dogs.Dog

cat-application
  ├ com.wang.animals.cats.Cat
  └ application.properties // animalClass=com.wang.animals.cats.Cat
```

Both `dog-application` and `cat-application` depend on `base-animals` and possibly other projects but don't need to know each other. Your build could then create a `dog-application.jar` and a `cat-application.jar` that could be shipped/handled as you like.

To determine which `Animal` to use at runtime I'd implement an `AnimalFactory` that looks up the `Animal` implementation of choice by some properties file or system properties, or something similar (I omitted exception handling and stuff as this is an example only):

```
public class AnimalFactory {

  public static Animal createAnimal() throws Exception {
    final String animalClassName = getThisValueFromApplicationProperties();
    return Class.forName(animalClassName).getConstructor().newInstance();
  }
}
```

If you don't care about `Cat` and `Dog` being shipped together you could also move them to the `base-animals` project and just keep the `application.properties` file in the `dog-application` and `cat-application`. You would however need to ship both applications with **all** dependencies needed by `Cat` **and** `Dog.`

Comment: Could you clarify - separate Maven projects as in having two completely independent source code trees/maven projects A and B, deleting Cat from A and deleting Dog from B, and having a different set of dependencies in projects A and B?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 3):

If 'choice' is a static, final primitive or String it will be set at compile time.

```
static final int choice = 0;
```

I would question why this is necessary though?  It seems like a lot of complexity to save what will likely be negligible JAR size.  If there really are significant differences, then separate Maven projects with their own dependencies would be a better approach.

Comment: by 'separate Maven projects' here you consider just simply building two different instances without Dog/Cat classes respectively?

Comment: Yes.  If they are really that separate, the common code will only use 'Animal'.  Then each project would build/pull in a dependency that has all the Cat or Dog stuff respectively.   If Cat or Dog are intermixed in the common code, then your idea probably doesn't makes sense and it should be just one project

Answer (score 2):

First I assume that you don't want to *build* `Dog` when you use `Cat`, and build `Cat` when you use `Dog`.

Next I assume that in your program you never ever mention `Dog` and `Cat` directly, else *both* of them became a compilation dependency. Anywhere but the `Cat` and `Dog` implementations, you should refer to the interface `Animal` only.

Then you can use [`Class.forName`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-) to look up a particular `Cat` or `Dog`, pass it through `isSubclass` to make sure it implements `Animal`, look up a constructor, invoke it, and cast the resulting object to `Animal`.

The above makes most sense when you ship your app as a jar, but don't ship either `cat.jar` or `dog.jar` along with it, e.g. for licensing reasons, or because they use different native code dependencies, etc.

Comment: Ah, hello reflection.  How about if I give up on Dog and Cat implementing a common interface and have only "Animal" class and two different source code files Animal.java (implementing Cat and Dog)? Would there be a way to tell Maven which one to use at compile time?

Comment: ^ I suppose the @dpr's answer discusses that?